# gorm not establishing foreign key relationshop in the database schema

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I have the following 2 `gorm` models

```
// Day is a corresponding day entry
type Day struct {
    gorm.Model
    Dateday   string         `json:"dateday" gorm:"type:date;NOT NULL"`
    Nameday   string         `json:"nameday" gorm:"type:varchar(100);NOT NULL"`
    Something sql.NullString `json:"something"`
    Holyday   bool           `json:"holyday"`
}

type Week struct {
    gorm.Model
    Start Day
    End   Day
}
```

However, after performing the migrations

```
db.AutoMigrate(&Day{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Week{})
```

logging into the db and describing table `weeks`

```
postgres-# \d+ weeks;
                                                          Table "public.weeks"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default              | Storage | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('weeks_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                   | plain   |              |
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                   | plain   |              |
 deleted_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                   | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "weeks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_weeks_deleted_at" btree (deleted_at)
```

I don't see the `start` / `end` fields, that should presumably also be Foreign Key to the `day` table (that does exist)

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set one-to-one relationship you need to also add id field to struct. By default you should name it as `[YourFieldName]ID`, if you want to use some other name for id field, you can do it via tag (see [docs for more details](http://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html)), for example:

```
type Week struct {
    gorm.Model
    Start    Day
    End      Day `gorm:"foreignkey:EndRefer"`
    StartID  uint
    EndRefer uint
}
```

But beware, `AutoMigrate` can't create foreign key constraint([here's related issue](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/450)). You have to set it yourself with [`AddForeignKey` method](http://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Add-Foreign-Key).

Comment: thanks. I see that this has been an extremely long running issue; the author states that it is solved in `v2` but [I don't know](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/450#issuecomment-602122730) how to explicitly import `v2`.